Fancyhdr - different fancypagestyle with geometry footer issues
I've made several searches for this issue and found posts similar but not including geometry and newgeometry. So I'm sorry if there are duplicates.
My goal is:

firstpage: headerA, footerA
other pages: headerB, footerB

edit: The height of headerA and headerB are usually different.
My issue is that when I make the headheight (40 mm instead of 15 mm) of firstpage larger the footer on page 1 disappears.
Everything is dynamically created with software. So I can't really fiddle with details the way I could if I wrote the latex code by hand. For example there are no \newpage commands, except in the end. The software relies on latex (xelatex) to handle pages in case content fills the page. That's why I've added spacing below the tables to simulate that content pushes things to the next page.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[total={210mm,297mm}, top=10mm, foot=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \newgeometry{total={210mm,297mm}, head=40mm, foot=10mm, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm, includeheadfoot}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{
        \begin{tabular}{ l }
            Some Large header\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \fancyfoot[L]{firstpage footer}
}
\fancypagestyle{otherpage}{
    \newgeometry{total={210mm,297mm}, head=15mm, foot=10mm, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm, includeheadfoot}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{
        \begin{tabular}{ l }
            Some smaller header\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \fancyfoot[L]{otherpage footer}
}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{otherpage}
    \thispagestyle{firstpage}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{c}
    Page 1\tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}\\[250mm]
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    Page 2\tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}\\[250mm]
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    Page 3\tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}
    \newpage
\end{document}


You cannot have a \newgeometry inside a page style. The page style is added after the page is built, so way too late. Please start over and explain in better detail what your end goal is.

As @daleif has noted, using \newgeometry in a page header or so, is not going to work because the page body has already been built. In general \newgeometry should be given just after a \newpage or at least very soon after. So in your case where the page break between the first and second pages is unknown in advance, that won't work.
My advice for these cases (i.e. first page different from the others), is to keep the geometry for all pages the same, and just add a larger header to the first page with the \pagestyle{firstpage}. The header will then overwrite the first part of the text, but you can compensate that by adding a \vspace*{delta}, where you have to experiment to find the delta length.
Because you have a too large header on the first page, fancyhdr will give a warning. If you find that annoying you can use the nocheck option for fancyhdr.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[total={210mm,297mm}, top=10mm, head=15mm, foot=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{~\\[35mm] % Make the header large - just for demonstration
        \begin{tabular}{ l }
            Some Large header\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \fancyfoot[L]{firstpage footer}
}
\fancypagestyle{otherpage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{
        \begin{tabular}{ l }
            Some smaller header\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \fancyfoot[L]{otherpage footer}
}
\begin{document}
   \vspace*{20mm}
    \pagestyle{otherpage}
    \thispagestyle{firstpage}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{c}
    Page 1\tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}\\[250mm]
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    Page 2\tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}\\[250mm]
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    Page 3\tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}
    \newpage
\end{document}


Thank you @pieter! Since I have functions that calculate the height of the header I could use those for calculating the vspace instead. I would have liked a more elegant solution but I understand that there maybe isn't a better solution for this problem. Therefor I'm hesitant to mark your answer as 'the accepted answer' but I'll do that for now at least.
